# Get a UIButton programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I want to change a UIButton programmatically, is that possible?
Without any interaction.

Can I get the objects in the view somehow? If I can get them I can iterate through them and get the UIButton I want and change it to what I want to.

Comment: all the objects within a view can be obtained using `view.subviews` it as array with all the objects in that view, iterate the array to get ur button and use accordingly..

Comment: Yes, I use the self.subviews array an iterate though it in another view where it was to many buttons to tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

If you're dealing with a dynamic number of buttons, then using tags is what you need.
When inserting your `UIButton` (either via Interface Builder or programatically), you can assign it a tag. As in, `view.tag = 6`. This means you can pull out a particular instance of your button from it's super view.

In practise, you would typically add your button via:

```
UIButton* btn = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...];
....
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

The additional step is assigning a tag (how you keep track of your tags is up to you).

```
btn.tag = 44;
```

In order to access it again, I can extract it from my view.

```
UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:44];
```

And this produces the same instance that I initially created.

If you wanted to replace it, you simply remove the old one, and create+add the new one.

```
[btn removeFromSuperview];
UIButton* btn2 = [UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...];
...
[self.view addSubview:btn2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link your button to its controller from the xib using the referencing outlet tab section. you will then have a reference to your button so you dont have to iterate through all your subviews. simply select your xib and open the side utility menu. select your button and click the connections inspector on the utility menu. click and drag the circle next to "new referencing outlet" to your controller's .h file.